# Prolog get friends

Tags: list, prolog

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).

friendof(mark, frank).
friendof(mark, sylvie).
friendof(john, sylvie).
friendof(marie, chris).


symmetrical(X, Y) :- friendof(X, Y).
symmetrical(X, Y) :- friendof(Y, X).

:- dynamic(friendlist/1).

friends(Friend, LL)  :-
   asserta(friendlist([])),
   friends2(Friend)
   retract(friendlist(LL)).
friends2(F) :-
```

What I have to do is, using friends as it is (so, using `friends2/1`), get all the friends of mark as such:

`?-friends (mark, X).`  would give this list, (take note of the order in which they appear):
`X = [sylvie, frank]`

I was told many things, of which I should be doing
`symmetrical(..),retract(..),assert(..),fail.`

But it's just not working to put the list back in friendlist from `friends2/1`.
Can someone show me how it's done?

It's really important!

Thanks!

EDIT1:

These are some attempts at getting it to work.

```
friends2(F) :- findall(B,symmetrical(A,B),B).
symmetrical(F,Y),retract(friendlis([Y:_])),assert(...
%symmetrical(..),retract(..),assert(..),fail.
```

Comment: Formatting code is a pretty good thing to utilize. It'll be easier to read....

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to use it.

Comment: What does `friendlis([Y:_])` mean?

Comment: I'm trying to put the Y value in friendlist... (oh, and it's friendlist, I made a mistake and wrote friendlis).

Comment: It doesn't work, I'm just showing my progress, which is actually not progress...

Comment: What's the colon (`:`) for? Also, what is the meaning of the predicate, `friends(X, Y)` you are wanting to implement? your example shows `friends(mark, X)` would yield `[sylvie, john]`, but it wouldn't include `frank`?

Comment: Ahh! My bad! It's supposed to include [sylvie, frank] in that order. john has nothing to do with it.

The : is for the head, I think if you insert to the head, when a new element comes in after, it'll go to tail and the new element will be head now.

Comment: Have you looked at Prolog list syntax? There's no colon involved. And why does the order have to be `sylvie` followed by `frank`? What's the "rule" for the order? I think you should look at the Prolog error messages and clean up the basic syntax.

Comment: I can't write the actual code for it because apparently the logic is wrong. I need to get the friends and put them in friendlist which will be returned by friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're doing it *much* more complex that actually is.

Most importantly: assert/retract should *not* be used for computing temporary relations in DB. Use them only to change *knowledge* - that is, well structured and meaningful relations that need to be persistent for the duration of the program.

For your task, try

```
friends_of(Person, Friends) :-
  setof(Friend, (friendof(Person, Friend) ; friendof(Friend, Person)), Friends).
```

*edit* Of course, I don't understand *why* you need to do it so much more complicated... maybe you need to show you are able to issue modification to DB ? I fear you will discover that such problem (keeping a *coherent* db state) is much more difficult than foreseen, and learning to assert/retract useless relations will not help you much. Anyway...

```
friends(Friend, LL)  :-
   asserta(friendlist([])),
   friends2(Friend),
   retract(friendlist(LL)), !.

friends2(F) :-
   ( friendof(F, P) ; friendof(P, F) ),
   retract(friendlist(L)), 
   assert(friendlist([P|L])),
   fail.
friends2(_).
```

could work for you...

Comment: I have to use friends and friends2

Comment: So, you have to use a `friends` predicate with two arguments and a `friends2` predicate with one argument? Sounds like a poor and confusing choice of predicate names.